# Как управлять вспышкой камеры, каждым светодиодом по отдельности?

Tags: java, android

На смартфоне стоит вспышка из 4х светодиодов (2 холодных, 2 теплых). Возможно ли управлять каждым этим светодиодом по отдельности?
Телефон Meizu M6 Note. Нужно написать программу, чтобы при уведомлениях вспышка  сначало светила 2-мя тёплыми светодиодами, а затем 2-мя холодными.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это довольно сложно... - возможно даже невозможно... варианты такие:

1. Стандартный интерфейс Java для управления камерой - пакет [android.hardware.camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) - не содержит запрашиваемых вами фич, ну разве что в посмотреть в отладчике имплементацию класса [CameraDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice) - иногда там бывают приватные методы, до которых можно достучаться через рефлексию.
2. Попробовать залезть в исходники прошивки Meizu - [вроде валяются здесь](https://github.com/loneyjs/android_kernel_meizu_msm8953) и поискать там какие-то ошметки кода и через JNI подцепиться к ним. Судя по всему исходники управления [вспышкой здесь](https://github.com/loneyjs/android_kernel_meizu_msm8953/tree/4979f9d94a027c3c5f0e1d209201b980fab95719/drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/flash) и там даже есть методы `msm_flash_low()` и `msm_flash_high()` - возможно это они и есть. Вызвать их будет сложно, зависит от декларации объявленных интерфейсов, возможно придется писать на NDK свои интерфейсы (скорее всего).
3. У нормальных аппаратов бывают свои кастомные девелоперские API: например у Самсунгов, Motorol, LG и т.д., но в случае Meizu - это не работает.